# Как сложить два массива в массиве объектов

Tags: javascript

Есть массив в котором находятся объекты с массивом данных.

Нужно получить сумму всех элементов массива объектов и добавить каждую сумму в объект, затем нужно получить сумму двух объектов и так же добавить в объект.

Так же нужно сложить элементы из массива первого объекта с элементами из массива второго эл и добавить в массив с суммой каждого свойства т.е объект а) [1,2,3] и объект б) [4,5,6] сложить их и получить на выходе [ 5,7,9]

Смог получить сумму двух элементов массива но вариант оказался весьма деревянным, т.к привязан к свойству первого объекта

```js
function chartSumm(arr) {
  let obj,
    firstArr = [],
    lastArr = [],
    sumArray = []

  arr.forEach(function(item, index) {
    for (let el in item.data) {
      if (item.label === 'Эккономия на аннуляции') {
        firstArr = item.data;
      } else {
        lastArr = item.data
      }
    }
  });
  let firstObjSum = firstArr.reduce(function(prev, curr, index) {
    return prev + curr
  });
  let twoObjSum = lastArr.reduce(function(prev, curr, index) {
    return prev + curr
  });

  obj = {
    'Цена у стойки': firstObjSum,
    'Аннуляция без штрафа': twoObjSum,
    'Общая экономия': firstObjSum + twoObjSum
  };
  console.log(obj)
}

chartSumm([{
    label: 'Эккономия на аннуляции',
    backgroundColor: '#ef9d4d',
    data: [1000, 400, 1500, 1500, 3000, 4000]
  },
  {
    label: 'Экономия на цене у стойки',
    backgroundColor: '#476e8f',
    data: [1170, 460, 2000, 2500, 2700, 4000]
  },
])
```

Comment: так у тебя разные поля во входных объектах и в выходных, тебе в любом случае их как-то связывать придется.

Comment: @Grundy ну я просто думаю вдруг есть более универсальный вариант, ведь если добавить еще объект то во второй массив полетит 2 массива уже)

Comment: конечно есть, если оставлять те же label

Comment: @Grundy ну да, была еще идея сразу обращаться к нужному массиву без первых циклов, но это уже через чур такое)
но момент когда заканчивается первый цикл я не знаю как еще можно определить без привязки к данным)

Comment: Какой смысл в `for (let el in item.data)`? Вы с этим циклом вообще ни чего не делаете, просто по 6 раз вставляете `item.data` в `firstArr`  и `lastArr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как лейблы разные, то их в любом случае придется прописывать. Чтобы сделать функцию более универсальной ( и не для только лишь 2 обхектов) можно вынести лейбл результата в объект. Я так же вынес лейбл `Общая Экономия` отдельно из функцию, но можно задавать его и внутри.

```js
function chartSumm(arr, sumLabel, elementSumLabel) {
  var result = {};
  result[sumLabel] = 0;
  result[elementSumLabel] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

  arr.forEach(function(item, index) {
    result[item.resultLabel] = 0;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < item.data.length; i++) {
      result[elementSumLabel][i] += item.data[i];
      result[item.resultLabel] += item.data[i]
    }
    
    result[sumLabel] += result[item.resultLabel];
  });
    
  return result;
}

var info = chartSumm([{
    label: 'Эккономия на аннуляции',
    resultLabel: 'Цена у стойки',
    backgroundColor: '#ef9d4d',
    data: [1000, 400, 1500, 1500, 3000, 4000]
  },
  {
    label: 'Экономия на цене у стойки',
    resultLabel: 'Аннуляция без штрафа',
    backgroundColor: '#476e8f',
    data: [1170, 460, 2000, 2500, 2700, 4000]
  },
], 'Общая экономия', 'Сумма элементов');

console.log(info);
```

Comment: а как быть с массивом сумм элементов?
`Так же нужно сложить элементы из массива первого объекта с элементами из массива второго эл и добавить в массив с суммой каждого свойства т.е объект а) [1,2,3] и объект б) [4,5,6] сложить их и получить на выходе [ 5,7,9]`

Comment: @Drop обновил ответ